# stackoverflow login system..different from general practise...?

Tags: security, passwords, login-control

I have read in many security related articles that **on an incorrect login** to a site the site should not specify whether the username or password is incorrect..

And This is true in practice also...Most sites report invalid login as

`Either Username or password incorrect`

**What are the reasons that this type of error message is encouraged....??**

If this really is the correct method, then why does stackoverflow site show what exactly is incorrect rather than the general practice...?